# MongoDB NodeJS driver's browserify compatibility (debugging help)

Tags: node.js, lambda, node-mongodb-native, serverless-framework

Trying to figure out what's the problem that I can't browserify mongodb native nodejs driver. I'm assuming there is something wrong here in my setup as I tried googling if there was any known current compatibility problem with MongoDB NodeJS driver and browserify but nothing conclusive came up after couple days trying ;(

After running my code on browserify I get a

```
TypeError: require(...).native is not a function
```

I read on the driver's github repo that this driver depends on some native functionality and on kerberos and node-gyp. I installed the driver on my machine without any problem with npm install mongodb --save so I don't know if that might be the case.

I ran out of debugging ideas, so I'm turning to the blessed SO community 
:)

I'm developing for AWS Lambda using the Serverless Framework (so I'm concerned if the driver will actually run on a Lambda instance as the driver requires some native functionality...). Here is my testing code

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var x = "Hello NodeJS";

console.log(x);

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", (err, db) => {
  console.log("Error null? " + (err == null ? "YES" : "NO"));
  console.log("DB null? " + (db == null ? "YES" : "NO"));
});
```

I was using some ES6 syntax like import and let bc in my original code I also transform it with babelify but removed, so just plain browserify creates some problem

I ran it like

```
browserify simple.js -o browserified.js
```

If someone can shed a light on this, I'd appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Can you just use `babel` directly? Browserify seems like the wrong tool for this. You *might* be able to make it work, but it's not really what browserify was designed to handle.

Comment: I thought about that, good idea but I'm using the serverless framework which organizes and deploys the code to AWS Lambda, they have the concepts of plug-ins that hook into the deployment process. They have this optimizer plugin which browserifies and use babel as browserify's plugin so I was trying to mimic the same method as I'll be using this for the whole process. I couldn't find another plugin with only babel. They now have a babel-runtime that I'm looking into now, that I might be able to use. But people can't use the mongo driver with browserify? Thanks for commenting

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I'm almost positive that they can't use it in a browser, but you seem to be using browserify to transpile and use in node. I'm not sure what sort of shenanigans would go on there, but I know browserify *tries* to [shim some stuff](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility), but there's no way it can get them all, since node can do things browsers can't (interact with fs, etc). If `mongodb` uses any of those, I honestly have *no* idea what browserify would attempt to do to them.

Comment: @dvlsg Yes, I'm trying to use it in node. I believe they just use browserify for performance. I'll try to modify or create another plugin with just Babel to see if I can get it through. Thanks again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an issue at MongoDB JIRA server and I was confirmed the driver as of today doesn't run in the browser. Of course, I was not trying to run it in the browser, but in Node, but as my friend @dvlsg pointed in the comments of my question it is possible browserify shims some stuff important for the correct implementation of MongoDB driver. So if you're out there pulling your hair off as of today, try a workaround which does not include bundling up mongodb driver with browserify.

The driver maintainer confirmed he was working on a version that will work in the browser, which will possibly work the way I needed but it is not ready even for alpha release, hopefully if you're reading this in the future...

Comment: Any updates on this? Where is the thread with the driver maintainer?

Comment: @ericsoco Here is the thread. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-698 Hope it helps...