# bundle.js bundle.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies/../../package.json'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, browserify

I am getting the below error:

`bundle.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules\mongodb-ore\lib\topologies/../../package.json'`

Here is my version detial:

OS: Windows10

MongoDB: 2.2.16

MongoDB-core: 2.1.2

Node: 6.9.2

I have used `npm install bson-ext` and changed `\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\bson-ext\ext\index.js` to

```
try {
// Load the precompiled win32 binary
if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "x64") {
  bson = require('bson');
} else if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "ia32") {
  bson = require('bson');
} else {
  bson = require('bson');
}
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    // Attempt to load the release bson version
    try {
        bson = require('bindings')('bson.node');
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using       pure JS version");
    }
}
```

while the original is:

```
bson = require('./win32/x64/bson');
```

because when I try `browserify range.js > bundle.js`, it cannot find `bson-ext module` in `mongoDB-core`.

I am not sure whether this kind of operation may cause the above error.

Here is my package.json file :

```
"dependencies": {
"browserify": "^13.1.1",
"bson": "^1.0.1",
"d3": "^4.4.0",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"hbs": "^4.0.1",
"jsdom": "^9.9.1",
"mongodb": "^2.2.16",
"mongodb-core": "^2.1.2"
}
```

Comment: Seeing the same problem on OSX 10.10, `node@5.9.1`. I only have `"mongodb": "^2.2.16"` in my `package.json, since `npm` should install deps automatically. However, I see that `mongodb-core` uses an `optionalPeerDependencies` field with `bson-ext`, and there are a couple blocks in `mongodb-core` that attempt to optionally require `bson-ext`. For some reason, the native `bson-ext` libs didn't compile for me on npm's `install` script, so I commented out the optional requires,... and while my app compiles, I still hit the same problem in the OP. Browserify may not be resolving that path correctly?

Comment: More here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902720/mongodb-nodejs-drivers-browserify-compatibility-debugging-help
points to mongodb + browserify as a bad combination...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to confirm this yet, but I think the problem is that MongoDB's JavaScript (Node.js) driver is not intended for use in a browser, for security reasons. Not clear if the problem in the OP is due to Browserify incorrectly resolving relative paths or something else, but regardless the preferred technique is to proxy requests to your MongoDB instance via a Node server.

Mongo lists off-the-shelf solutions for this here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/

Note also the `--rest` option, which allows an application to read directly from the DB via a URL schema:
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api

As the docs mention, this is not good practice for security concerns, but may help with prototyping.

Comment: Ugh, unfortunately the Simple REST API doesn't have a CORS header so you can't use it on its own to query the DB from the browser. Kinda useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is just the problem. I am not familiar with Node.js and incorrectly require mongoDB  in my browser used `.js` file. I have come across this problem the second time a few days before and solved by  removing `require('mongodb')`.from my `.js` browser used file.